# Excel Dynamic Column Reference in Formula

Tags: excel, dynamic, reference, excel-formula

I want to update the cell reference in C3 depending on the 'Current Day'.

For example, if 'Current Day' is 'Thu' then I'd like C3 to be 'Z3'

Any suggestions to get me started? webpages to read?

[image]

Comment: Use index/match or hlookup to find the cell address (Z3), then indirect to get the value (34.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value on the basis of **Current Day** use the following formula:

```
=HLOOKUP(H3,$I$2:$O$3,2,FALSE)
```

See image for reference

[image]

On seeing the formula in image attached probably you are looking for ***INDIRECT*** function:

```
=INDIRECT("'5+ 000""s By Day'!" & C3)
```

You can combine both in one formula as

```
=INDIRECT("'5+ 000""s By Day'!" & HLOOKUP(H3,$I$2:$O$3,2,FALSE))
```

For details on `INDIRECT` function see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile by doing the INDIRECT formula

Comment: thanks for the INDIRECT function, that was exactly what I needed to solve my issue. google led me here.  allowed me to pull up a value from another cell based on the string version of the cell location.  
 cheers!   =INDIRECT("'worksheet1'!R$1")

Answer (score 1):

A `hlookup()` would do it - `=HLOOKUP(TEXT(TODAY(),"DDD"),I2:O3,2,0)`